# Test a function that calls a http service inside component Angular5

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I need to test this function.

When I click this function `getallproductcomponent()`, execute this service function `getallproductservice()` and return all products. Any idea please, how to test both in component?

```
  getallproductcomponent() {
    this.ws.getallproductservice().subscribe(
      item=> {
        this.item= item;
      }
    );
  }
```

I can testing only `getallproductservice`. Below you can see my scripts that's work good. How to testing   `getallproductcomponent() {}`

```
it('testing',
    async(inject([ProductService], (service: ProductService) => {
        TestBed.get(MockBackend).connections.subscribe(
            (connection: MockConnection) => connection.mockRespond(new Response(
                new ResponseOptions({
                                    })
            ))
        );
        service.getallproductservice().subscribe(items => {
            expect(items[0].alarmdesc).toEqual('call');
        });
    })))
```

Any idea please?

Edit:

```
it('should call service.getallproductservice when getallproductcomponent', done => {
    const mock = [ {id: 1, alarmdesc: 'test12'}];
    component['ws'].getallproductservice = () => Observable.of(mock);
    spyOn(component['ws'].and.callThrough();

    component['ws'].getallproductservice ().subscribe(items => {
        expect(component['ws'].getallproductservice ).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(component.item).toBe(mock);
        done();
    });
    component.getallproductcomponent();
}));
```

Result:

1: In `component['ws'].getallproductservice = () => Observable.of(mock);`
Error:

> Type '() => Observable<{ id: number; alarmdesc: string; }[]>' is not
>   assignable to type '() => Observable'.

2: In `spyOn(component['ws'].and.callThrough();`
Error:

> [ts] Property 'and' does not exist on type 'ProductService'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component you're supposed to test your service is being called. You're not supposed to test if your service is calling an endpoint : that will be done in the tests of your service.

This means that you just have to test that :

```js
it('should call service.getallproductservice when getallproductcomponent', done => {
  const mock = [/* mock of your objects */];
  component['ws'].getallproductservice = () => Observable.of(mock);
  spyOn(component['ws'], 'getallproductservice').and.callThrough();

  component['ws'].getallproductservice().subscribe(() => {
    expect(component['ws'].getallproductservice).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.item).toBe(mock);
    done();
  });

  component.getallproductcomponent();
});
```

Comment: Thnx for answer. `TypeError: Cannot set property 'getallproductservice' of undefined` I tried:     ` component['ws'].getallproductservice().subscribe(() => { console.log(component.item)...`  And not execute,nothing happens. `getallproductservice()` not execute.

Comment: Your service has to be called ws, that's from your own code. Otherwise, use the name you gave instead.

Comment: When I put ws, `Type '() => Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type '() => Observable<Products[]>'.
  Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Products[]>'.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Products[]'.`

Comment: And I meant to write mock instead of true, my bad ! I edited my answer

Comment: When I write mock like this `  const mock = [ {id: 1, alarmdesc: 'test12'}];` is good? I tried and `[ts] Property 'and' does not exist on type 'ProductService'.
`

Comment: 1 . Type your variables accordingly and 2. I forgot a parenthesis, `spyOn(component['ws']).and.callThrough()`

Comment: 2. `[ts] Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
[ts] Property 'and' does not exist on type 'ProductService'.`

Comment: `spyOn(component['ws'], 'getallproductservice').and.callThrough()`, I'm sorry, I'm not at my best at all ...

Comment: Thank you. Now `component['ws'].getallproductservice().subscribe(() => {...` works, but this `component.getallproductcomponent();`is undefined